# TreePlot does not give a "binary-looking" tree for a binary tree

Tags: plotting, trees

I use the following code to generate a binary tree with root 1.

```
TreePlot[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 3 -> 7, 4 -> 8, 
  4 -> 9, 5 -> 10, 5 -> 11, 6 -> 12, 6 -> 13, 7 -> 14, 7 -> 15, 
  8 -> 16, 8 -> 17, 10 -> 18, 10 -> 19, 11 -> 20, 11 -> 21, 13 -> 22, 
  13 -> 23, 15 -> 24, 18 -> 25, 18 -> 26, 19 -> 27, 19 -> 28, 
  25 -> 29, 25 -> 30, 26 -> 31, 31 -> 32, 31 -> 33}, 
 VertexLabeling -> True]
```

However, it generates a non-binary-looking tree with 2 as the "root".
[image]

Anyone has solution for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The documentation says:

> *TreePlot[g]* attempts to choose the root so as to make trees have as
>   few layers as possible.

What it does not say is that edge directions are ignored when determining the root node.  The result is that `TreePlot` rejects the expected tree rooted at *1* because it has eight layers as opposed to the seven layers obtained with *2* as the root.

While this behaviour might be less than useful, the good news is that if we explicitly specify the proper root node then the tree is rendered nicely:

```
TreePlot[
  { 1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 3 -> 7, 4 -> 8
  , 4 -> 9, 5 -> 10, 5 -> 11, 6 -> 12, 6 -> 13, 7 -> 14, 7 -> 15
  , 8 -> 16, 8 -> 17, 10 -> 18, 10 -> 19, 11 -> 20, 11 -> 21
  , 13 -> 22, 13 -> 23, 15 -> 24, 18 -> 25, 18 -> 26, 19 -> 27
  , 19 -> 28, 25 -> 29, 25 -> 30, 26 -> 31, 31 -> 32, 31 -> 33
  }
, Top
, 1
, VertexLabeling -> True
]
```

[image]

Note the addition of the arguments `Top` and `1` which indicate that the tree should be rooted at the top of the diagram and that the root node should be `1`.